# Failed to launch simulated application: iPhone Simulator failed to find the process ID of com.iAndApp.BlockPop

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm having this annoyning problem giving this message in the console: Failed to launch simulated application: iPhone Simulator failed to find the process ID of com.iAndApp.BlockPop.

When trying to Build and Run, the application builds fine. The simulator starts but doesn't start the application. However, it manages to do something since the icon for the app is installed in the simulator.

I have been searching to find the answer and tried a couple of things, none that worked.

This happens for both new and old projects. I.e. when I create a new project I will receive the same error message. I've tried several projects of which all get the same error, so it's not related to the code (and successful builds proves it).

Among other things I have updated to xCode 3.2.2. in order to try to solve the problem. Using Mac OSX 10.6.3.

Here are the logs:

```
1. 2010-05-30 17.20.39  SpringBoard[15713]  Unable to create CFServerConnection. Telephony state may be incorrect.
2010-05-30 17.20.40 SpringBoard[15713]  Unable to create CFServerConnection. Telephony state may be incorrect.
2010-05-30 17.20.40 SpringBoard[15713]  Unable to create CFServerConnection. Telephony state may be incorrect.
2010-05-30 17.20.40 SpringBoard[15713]  Unable to create CFServerConnection. Telephony state may be incorrect.
2010-05-30 17.20.40 SpringBoard[15713]  Can't find the translation dictionary, loadTranslationDictionaries
2010-05-30 17.20.40 SpringBoard[15713]  Unable to create CFServerConnection. Telephony state may be incorrect.
2010-05-30 17.20.40 SpringBoard[15713]  Unable to create CFServerConnection. Telephony state may be incorrect.
2010-05-30 17.20.41 SpringBoard[15713]  Launchd returned an unexpected type or didn't return a value for job label UIKitApplication:com.iAndApp.BlockPop[0x8abd] with job key PID
2010-05-30 17.20.41 SpringBoard[15713]  Unable to create CFServerConnection. Telephony state may be incorrect.
2010-05-30 17.21.10 Xcode[15496]    Error launching simulated application: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=1 UserInfo=0x200edcc00 "iPhone Simulator failed to find the process ID of com.iAndApp.BlockPop."

2. Form system.log
May 30 17:20:39 Niklas-Johanssons-Mac-mini mobile_installationd[15712]: a0bc84e0 init_simulator_paths: No simulator root specified. Falling back to environment variable.
May 30 17:20:39: --- last message repeated 5 times ---
May 30 17:20:39 Niklas-Johanssons-Mac-mini mobile_installationd[15712]: b0081000 init_simulator_paths: No simulator root specified. Falling back to environment variable.
May 30 17:20:39: --- last message repeated 1 time ---
May 30 17:20:39 Niklas-Johanssons-Mac-mini mobile_installationd[15712]: b0081000 load_application_info: Could not load signer identity from /Users/Niklas/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.0/Applications/1CD7E4BA-14D3-45A5-A05E-E552C04BCD4D/BlockPopLite.app/BlockPopLite
May 30 17:20:39 Niklas-Johanssons-Mac-mini mobile_installationd[15712]: b0081000 load_application_info: Could not load signer identity from /Users/Niklas/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.0/Applications/62585F19-5FAD-4548-89DF-C9AE621FCCD7/SysSound.app/SysSound
May 30 17:20:39 Niklas-Johanssons-Mac-mini mobile_installationd[15712]: b0081000 load_application_info: Could not load signer identity from /Users/Niklas/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.0/Applications/81AA51A5-7BFC-442F-BFF8-91E9C6EF13CD/BlockPop.app/BlockPop
May 30 17:20:39 Niklas-Johanssons-Mac-mini mobile_installationd[15712]: b0103000 load_application_info: Could not load signer identity from /Users/Niklas/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.0/Applications/A2DCBF96-8F15-4527-BDF1-BD90B34D401C/BlockPop.app/BlockPop
May 30 17:20:39 Niklas-Johanssons-Mac-mini mobile_installationd[15712]: b0081000 init_simulator_paths: No simulator root specified. Falling back to environment variable.
May 30 17:20:39: --- last message repeated 1 time ---
May 30 17:20:39 Niklas-Johanssons-Mac-mini SpringBoard[15713]: Unable to create CFServerConnection. Telephony state may be incorrect.
May 30 17:20:40 Niklas-Johanssons-Mac-mini mobile_installationd[15712]: b0081000 init_simulator_paths: No simulator root specified. Falling back to environment variable.
May 30 17:20:40: --- last message repeated 1 time ---
May 30 17:20:40 Niklas-Johanssons-Mac-mini SpringBoard[15713]: Unable to create CFServerConnection. Telephony state may be incorrect.
May 30 17:20:40: --- last message repeated 2 times ---
May 30 17:20:40 Niklas-Johanssons-Mac-mini SpringBoard[15713]: Can't find the translation dictionary, loadTranslationDictionaries
May 30 17:20:40 Niklas-Johanssons-Mac-mini mobile_installationd[15712]: b0081000 init_simulator_paths: No simulator root specified. Falling back to environment variable.
May 30 17:20:40: --- last message repeated 3 times ---
May 30 17:20:40 Niklas-Johanssons-Mac-mini SpringBoard[15713]: Unable to create CFServerConnection. Telephony state may be incorrect.
May 30 17:20:41: --- last message repeated 1 time ---
May 30 17:20:41 Niklas-Johanssons-Mac-mini SpringBoard[15713]: Launchd returned an unexpected type or didn't return a value for job label UIKitApplication:com.iAndApp.BlockPop[0x8abd] with job key PID
May 30 17:20:41 Niklas-Johanssons-Mac-mini SpringBoard[15713]: Unable to create CFServerConnection. Telephony state may be incorrect.
May 30 17:21:10 Niklas-Johanssons-Mac-mini Xcode[15496]: Error launching simulated application: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=1 UserInfo=0x200edcc00 "iPhone Simulator failed to find the process ID of com.iAndApp.BlockPop."
```

Where do I start?

I am really stuck and would be most greatful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, restaring the computer made it work. Feels like PC... ;) Not sure if that was the sole solution or if the other activities I made helped out as well.

Answer (score 4):

From the simulator menu bar iPhone Simulator > Reset Content and Settings... finally did it for me after many computer restarts and Info.plist > Clear History attempts.